# jquery pass plugin callback to another plugin as parameter

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-plugins, parameter-passing

I have developed a plugin that gets data from online JSON file and creates a div with img element for OWL Carousel.

OWL Carousel by itself has an option to get custom data from JSON file, but as a parameter has a success callback for $.getJSON build in into carousel and it needs to be written in the same file. Now I just want this parameter to be passed to my plugin, which is written in separate file, so it builds function there and passes the result back to carousel.

My plugin code is:

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.matchCarousel = function(options) {

    var settings = { 'maxMatches': 10,
                     'success': null };
    if (options) { $.extend(settings, options); }

    var url = "url-from-online-json-file";

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
      var counter = 0;        
        $.each(data.doc[0].data[0].realcategories, function (index, value) {
            var realCat = this.name;
              $.each(this.tournaments, function (x, y) {
                tourName = this.name;
                var tourSeasName = this.seasontypename;
                $.each(this.matches, function (i, j) {
                  var resultHome = this.result.home;
                  var resultAway = this.result.away;
                  var teamHome = this.teams.home.name;
                  var teamHomeId = this.teams.home.uid;
                  var teamAway = this.teams.away.name;
                  var teamAwayId = this.teams.away.uid;
                  var time = this._dt.time;
                  var date = this._dt.date;
                  var statusId = this.status._id;
                  var statusName = this.status.name;
                  var matchId = this._id;

                  var content = $('div.slider div#owl-demo').append('<div id="' + index + i + '" class="item"><img id="' + index + i + '" class="slider ' + index + i + '" alt="' + realCat + ': ' + tourName + ' - ' + tourSeasName + '" /><p class="league">' + tourName + ' - ' + tourSeasName + '</p><p class="catName">' + realCat + '</p><div class="teams"><div class="team1"><img src="http://ls.betradar.com/ls/crest/big/' + teamHomeId + '.png" alt="' + teamHome + '"/ ><p class = "teamName">' + teamHome + '</p></div><div class="data"></div><div class="team2"><img src="http://ls.betradar.com/ls/crest/big/' + teamAwayId + '.png" alt="' + teamAway + '"/ ><p class = "teamName">' + teamAway + '</p></div></div><div class="statusName"></div></div>');
                  var itemData = $('.item[id=' + index + i + '] .data');
                  var itemStatus = $('.item[id=' + index + i + '] .statusName');
                  if (statusId == 0) {
                    $('img[id=' + index + i + ']').attr('src', 'images/bg-prematch.jpg');
                    itemData.html('<p class="dataText"><p class="vs">VS</p>' + time + '<br><span class="dateText">' + date + '</span></p>');
                    itemStatus.html('<span class="statusNameNS">' + statusName + '</span>');
                  } else if (statusId == 100) {
                    $('img[id=' + index + i + ']').attr('src', 'images/bg-postmatch.jpg');
                    itemData.html('<p class="result">' + resultHome + ':' + resultAway + '</p>');
                    itemStatus.html('<span class="statusNameEnd">' + statusName + '</span>');  
                  } else {
                    $('img[id=' + index + i + ']').attr('src', 'images/bg-live.jpg');
                    itemData.html('<p class="result">' + resultHome + ':' + resultAway + '</p>');
                    itemStatus.html('<span class="statusNameMid">' + statusName + '</span>');  
                  }
                  counter++;
                  return counter < settings['maxMatches'];                       
                });
                return counter < settings['maxMatches'];           
              });
            return counter < settings['maxMatches'];
        });
    });

  }
})(jQuery);
```

The jsonSuccess parameter is the callback and the logic should be implemented like this (from owner documentation):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
      jsonPath : 'url-from-online-json-file',
      jsonSuccess : customDataSuccess
    });

  function customDataSuccess(data){
    var content = "";
    for(var i in data["items"]){
      var img = data["items"][i].img;
      var alt = data["items"][i].alt;

      content += "<img src=\"" +img+ "\" alt=\"" +alt+ "\">"
    }
    $("#owl-demo").html(content);
  }    
});
```

So I don't want to "function customDataSuccess(data){ }" be created in this file, even though the carousel requires me to do it this way, but to be passed to my plugin as a parameter and then my plugin would return the value to carousel. My plugin is initiated like this:

```
$(document).matchCarousel();
```

So how can I initiate my plugin in the same file as OWL carousel, but pass it the jsonSuccess value of carousel parameter to my plugin as a parameter and then pass back the value to carousel? Because if I do it any other way carousel simply doesn't recognize the builded HTML structure.

The code can also be see on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2SqM/7/).

Thank you all for any help.

Comment: It might be helpful to load your example using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: never used jsfiddle before... how can it help me?

Comment: The gold standard for composing a good question on SO (or elsewhere) is to compose a [**Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example**](http://sscce.org/).  jsFidde helps you accomplish this when sharing code with strangers online.  If somethings not working, someone else can see the problem immediately.  It's a nice courtesy if your asking others for help, to do as much of the legwork as possible.

Comment: I see. I tried, here is the link [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2SqM/). I put the second JS code in CSS, since there isn't any more space to put in it. Hope it helps for someone to help me.

Comment: Good Start! However putting JS in the CSS block won't do anything.  It does not belong there.  There is no space constraint in fiddle, so just add the code where it belongs.  Are there external dependencies on code that you need to make the example run?  If so, you can add them to the external section on the left side of the page.

Comment: here is the working version [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2SqM/7/). it only lacks some of the local images, although everything is working